# What could cause writeLines to truncate a line?

Tags: r

I am using R and Google Sheets to write out R Markdown documents that produce an abstract booklet for a conference.

One of the operations reads the abstracts from a worksheet and writes it out to disk. This works perfectly for all but the very last abstract which truncates after 441 characters (so no suspicious thing like 256 or some such).

I have puzzled over whether there could be special characters hidden in the text, but a regex `[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]+` returns nothing. The string seems to display well past the truncation point when I inspect it so it is being read correctly. The one point that seems suspicious is that it does not complete the next (and final) write statement which is supposed to print a `<div></div>` block (it does this perfectly for every other entry).

This is the block of code that does the work. Not really that helpful, but it shows that I am not doing anything obviously silly (I hope).

```
abstract = abstractTbl %>% filter(subID == thisSubID)
writeLines(abstract$abstract, con = fileCon)
writeLines("<div style=\"page-break-before:always;\"></div>", con = fileCon)
```

Is there a `tryCatch` statement that I could write that would pick up a file writing error here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - it turns out remembering to close ALL the files helps. I was missing a final `close(fileCon)`.